# Fishpig custom blog landing page lists

Tags: magento2, wordpress

I am trying to split the posts list on the Fishpig blog landing page and have updated the wordpress_homepage_view.xml to include two new list files, the issue is the first one gets ignored and outputs the default list.phtml one.

```
<referenceBlock name="wp.postlist.wrapper" remove="true"/>

<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\PostType\View" name="wp.postlist.top.wrapper" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/list/home-top-wrapper.phtml">
    <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\Post\TopListPost" name="wp.post.list" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/home-top-list.phtml"/>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="main.content">
  <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\PostType\View" name="wp.postlist.bottom.wrapper" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/list/home-bottom-wrapper.phtml"  after="category.list">
    <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\Post\ListPost" name="wp.post.list" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/home-bottom-list.phtml" />
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Is this the default behaviour?

How can I get this page to use my custom posts list file instead of the default list file, or is there a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get these two files to work I updated the wordpress_homepage_view.xml file like this.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="wp.post.list.top.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-post-list">
        <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\PostType\View" name="wp.postlist.top.wrapper" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/list/home-top-wrapper.phtml">
            <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\Post\TopListPost" name="wp.post.list" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/list.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="main.content">
    <block name="category.list" template="FishPig_WordPress::page/category-list.phtml" after="content" />
    <container name="wp.post.list.bottom.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bottom-post-list" after="category.list">
        <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\PostType\View" name="wp.postlist.bottom.wrapper" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/list/home-bottom-wrapper.phtml">
            <block class="FishPig\WordPress\Block\Post\ListPost" name="wp.post.list" template="FishPig_WordPress::post/home-bottom-list.phtml" />
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

This ended up showing both files and from there I changed the posts to display the ones I required.